# Derived class instantiation in abstract base class in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance

My aim is to write an abstract base class which contains a method for deriving “child instances”. In this method already some computation is done which is common in all deriving classes.

The difficulty is that the base class is not able to create the child class on its own. So I introduced a type parameter `T` in my base class and a `protected abstract` method which shall return an instance of `T`.

```
public abstract class Base<T> where T : Base<T>
{
    public T GetChild()
    {
        string param = ComplexComputation();
        return NewInstanceFrom(param);
    }

    protected abstract T NewInstanceFrom(string param);
}

// --- somewhere else: ---

public class Derivative : Base<Derivative>
{
    public Derivative() { }

    protected sealed override Derivative NewInstanceFrom(string param)
    {
        return new Derivative(param);
    }

    private Derivative(string param)
    {
        // some configuration
    }
}
```

The disadvantage of this approach is that I cannot ensure that `NewInstanceFrom` is only invoked by the base class. It could also be invoked by classes inheriting from `Derivative`. That’s what I want to avoid.

So I could encapsulate the functionality in a private class or delegate:

```
public abstract class Base<T> where T : Base<T>
{
    public T GetChild()
    {
        string param = ComplexComputation();
        return subElementDerivator(param);
    }

    protected Base<T>(Func<string, T> subElementDerivator)
    {
        this.subElementDerivator = subElementDerivator;
    }

    private Func<string, T> subElementDerivator;
}

// --- somewhere else: ---

public class Derivative : Base<Derivative>
{
    public Derivative()
        : base(deriveSubElement)    
    {
    }

    private Derivative(string param)
        : base(deriveSubElement)
    {
        // some configuration
    }

    private static Derivative deriveSubElement(string param)
    {
        return new Derivative(param);
    }
}
```

But this introduces a new object.

Is there a simpler way to prevent access to a functionality (which the base class shall have access to) from heirs of `Derivative`?

Comment: Your 2nd code example is the only way I can think of to accomplish what you want.

Comment: It is weakness of `C#` that making generic factories is almost impossible. The above can be done by emitting opcodes I think.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with derived classes calling that method? Are you afraid that you will end up calling it yourself by mistake, or that third-party derived classes will call it without your consent?

Comment: @Jon You have brought good reasons. I’m developing a framework which I want to keep clean of methods which have no utility or are subverting the concept in the current context but can be callen.

Comment: If that is the case then setting `internal` visibility would solve your problem. That is how most of the .NET framework handles the same problem for its "special" constructors.

Answer (score 2):

You can use explicit interface implementation to hide your factory method. Any client can still call the `Create` method after casting but at least intellisense won't help developers.

```
public interface ISecretFactory<T>
{
    T Create(string param);
}

public abstract class Base<T> where T : Base<T>, ISecretFactory<T>
{
    public T GetChild()
    {
        // We are sure type T always implements ISecretFactory<T>
        var factory = this as ISecretFactory<T>;
        return factory.Create("base param");
    }
}

public class Derivative : Base<Derivative>, ISecretFactory<Derivative>
{
    public Derivative()
    {

    }

    private Derivative(string param)
    {

    }

    Derivative ISecretFactory<Derivative>.Create(string param)
    {
        return new Derivative(param);
    }
}

public class SecondDerivative : Derivative
{
    public void F()
    {
        // intellisense won't show Create method here.
        // But 'this as ISecretFactory<Derivative>' trick still works.
    }
}
```

Comment: It will always be possible to call anything you can call from elsewhere, so this is a pretty decent solution. Of course, it still smells somewhat, but if you really want a factory like this, this is not too bad.

Answer (score 0):

The additional object can be avoided by moving the `ComplexComputation` to the constructor of the base class and making the `GetChild` method abstract to let the deriving class pick a correct constructor there.

But how to return the computed value `param` in base constructor to the invoking derivate constructor? A possibility is to use the `out` parameter modifier. But because in C# 5.0 we are unfortunately not able to declare the variables before (or within) the base constructor call, we need to take the parameter along in the derivative constructor.

```
public abstract class Base<T> where T : Base<T>
{
    public abstract T GetChild();

    protected Base(T parent, out string param)
    {
        param = ComplexComputation();
    }

    protected Base()
    {
    }
}

// --- somewhere else: ---

public class Derivative : Base<Derivative>
{
    public sealed override Derivative GetChild()
    {
        string param;
        return new Derivative(this, out param);
    }

    public Derivative() { }

    private Derivative(Derivative parent, out string param)
        : base(parent, out param)
    {
        // some configuration
    }
}
```

In my case I could leave the `param` from the constructors away, instead I stored it in a `public` property.

This approach except the pesky necessary hack looks relatively clean to me, but it does not “scale” when multiple overloadings of `GetChild` are necessary.

Maybe in C# 6.0 it is possible to declare the `param` directly in the base constructor invocation. https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/magazine/dn683793.aspx